# How to Detect Leaks in C++ Builder 10.4 / Android app

Tags: memory-leaks, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Now that the memory management model has changed (ARC removed) in C++ Builder 10.4, I need to check my app for memory leaks. My research has revealed several tools for apps that run on Windows but not on Android.

I am testing my 32 bit app on Android 10.

Thanks in advance for any possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

You could compile your application in windows and use the tools of your research.

Comment: I had thought about that but not tried it. Thanks for reponding.